# ImportError - Unable to Import 'interp' from SciPy Module

Tags: python, scipy, pycaret

I encountered an ImportError while attempting to import PyCaret's classification module:

```
from pycaret.classification import*

ImportError: cannot import name 'interp' from 'scipy'
```

This error occurs when Python is unable to find the `interp` function within the SciPy library.

It seems that PyCaret's classification module relies on the 'interp' function from SciPy, but for some reason, Python is unable to locate it. This could be due to a version mismatch or a corrupted installation of the SciPy library.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to import `scipy` from your python interpreter directly? If you have `scipy` installed, try `from scipy import interp`. This should be the same as `numpy.interp`.

Comment: What version of SciPy are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This happened because there was a minor version release of SciPy `1.12.0` with breaking changes. You could fix this by installing the previous version with the command `pip install scipy==1.11.4`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you install :

```
pip install scipy #--> latest version
```

If you check the version:

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
```

output:

```
scipy 1.12.0
```

So you should use the following command:

```
%pip install scipy==1.11.4
```